# 1st React JS App, getting error, pls help. Code and error screenshot given

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[This is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PdYw.png)

This app is supposed to take data from an excel file "countries.xlsx" and depending on the value selected from the "Country" column, it shows all the data present in that row along with their respective column names. I originally planned to add a map, in which clicking on a country shows its data from the excel file, but don't know how to do that.

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
// import data from '../countries.xlsx';
import Link from 'next/link';

export const HomeLink = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <p>Welcome to my app!</p>
      <p>Click <Link href="/dashboard">here</Link> to go to the dashboard.</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default function CountryData() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState('');
  const [countryData, setCountryData] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const selectedCountry = e.target.value;
    setSelectedCountry(selectedCountry);
    const country = countries.find((country) => country.Country === selectedCountry);
    const countryData = Object.entries(country);
    setCountryData(Object.fromEntries(countryData));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const readExcel = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('../countries.xlsx');
      const data = await response.arrayBuffer();
      const workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });
      const sheet = workbook.Sheets['World'];
      const countries = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
      setCountries(countries);
    };
    readExcel();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <homeLink />
      <select onChange={handleChange}>
        <option value="">--Select Country--</option>
        {countries.map((country, index) => (
          <option key={index} value={country.Country}>
            {country.Country}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      {selectedCountry && (
  <div>

    <h2>{selectedCountry}</h2>

    <table>
      <thead>
        {Object.entries(countryData).map((key) => (
          <th key={key}>
            {key}
          </th>
        ))}
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          {Object.values(countryData).map((value, index) => (
            <td key={index}>
              {value}
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      
    </table>
  </div>
)}
      )
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: according to [npm readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) it seems you have first to set either  `XLSX.set_fs(fs);` or `XLSX.set_cptable(cpexcel);` before being able to use the XLSX functionnalities

Comment: Shows "Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'", even after  installing fs through npm and running the app again.